# OAuth2 Playground - Exchange of Token fails with DNS lookup error

Tags: oauth2-playground

I'm testing an OAuth2 server that I've written using the Playground.
Full configuration URL is [here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#step1&scopes=fp&url=https%3A//&content_type=application/json&http_method=GET&useDefaultOauthCred=unchecked&oauthEndpointSelect=Custom&oauthAuthEndpointValue=https%3A//localhost%3A8080/oauth2/api/authorize&oauthTokenEndpointValue=https%3A//localhost%3A8080/oauth2/api/token&oauthClientId=acme1&oauthClientSecret=secret&includeCredentials=checked&accessTokenType=bearer&autoRefreshToken=unchecked&accessType=offline&forceAprovalPrompt=checked&response_type=code).

Step 1 (authorisation grant) works perfectly. In Chrome I can see this request:

```
GET https://localhost:8080/oauth2/api/authorize?scope=fp&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&response_type=code&client_id=acme1&access_type=offline
```

Step 2 (token exchange) fails with:

```
POST /oauth2/api/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-length: 153
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground
code=2l0vf6n&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=acme1&client_secret=secret&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 115
Content-type: text/plain
An error occured while connecting to the server: DNS lookup failed for URL: https://localhost:8080/oauth2/api/token
```

Looking at the network I can see:

```
POST https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/exchangeAuthCode
```

with this body:

```
{"token_uri":"https://localhost:8080/oauth2/api/token","client_id":"acme1","client_secret":"secret","code":"5kns7"}
```

Is this how it's intended to work? That the OAuth server interactions, at least for token exchange, *has* to be on a public network?

It would be immensely useful if Step 2 can execute against a local server. Does anyone know how we can achieve this please?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth 2.0 Playground makes the auth code exchange requests on the server side because typically OAuth servers don't allow CORS requests for this request (at least for the auth code flow they should not allow CORS requests).

What you can do instead is expose your local service to the outside/internet. For this you can use services such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.me/) and you'll get a public URL to your local service which you'll be able to setup the Playground with.